# Как быстро обработать файл с большим количеством строк?

Tags: c++, qt

Работаю в QT Creator C++

Есть кнопка для открытия файла и чтения файла.
После записи файла в QStringList нужно совершать манипуляции с данными, а именно передавать их QPoint, что бы построить график.
Файл имеет 9 столбцов и больше 12 000 строчек, предполагается, что: первый столбец это Х , а все остальные это Y, таким образом получается 8 зависимостей или графиков.

Всё бы было хорошо, но всё встало на чтении txt файла, я так понимаю из-за перегруза памяти, вот возникает вопрос, как можно реализовать чтении так, чтобы всё происходило без вылетов и зависаний, на таком количестве элементов.

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_action_triggered() // кнопка для чтения 
{

  QFile file;
  QString f = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, QString("Выберите документ"), QDir::currentPath(), "*.txt");
  file.setFileName(f);
  if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {

    while (!file.atEnd()) {

      strList << file.readLine();

    }
    file.close();
  }

  void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() // кнопка для манипуляций с данными 
  {

    for (int i = 0; i < strList.size(); i++) {
      auto list1 = strList[i].split(" "); // достаёт строчку 

      for (int j = 0; j < list1.size(); j++) {
        auto d = QString(list1[j]).toDouble(); // достаёт отдельный элемент и преобразует его в 
        // предполагается, чтобы потом это число передавалось в QPointF, чтобы нарисовать график
      }

    }

    // *series << QPointF(  0 , 0);

  }
```

Как наверное уже поняли, изначальная идея, чтобы взять данные из файла и нарисовать график.
Данные эти с миограммы
Если знаете как эмулировать миограмму более простым способом, тоже просьба написать
А то голову уже сломал

Comment: так какая часть тормозит? загрузка из файла в QStrings или вывод графика?

Comment: Программа вылетает на моменте обработки данных, т.е. когда я нажимаю кнопку, которая преобразует элемент в число.  
Т.е. я загрузил файл, нажал кнопку и дальше с этими данными  должны начать происходить операции, но программа вылетает. 
Я пробовал не складывать всё в один QStringList и читать файл построчно, но видимо это не самое оптимальное решение, т.к. на этом моменте он тоже вылетает. 

Вот и возникает вопрос, как обработать файл так, чтобы не вылетало и при это можно было передать все точки на график ?

Comment: 12к элементов это не так много (если конечно у Вас больше 64кб памяти:) ). Нужно смотреть в файл, скорее всего там есть что то необычное. Я бы сократил файл до 2-3 строк и посмотрел, падает или нет. Если падает - показывайте укороченный файл, если нет - возьмите больше строк, например, пол файла. и методом деления найдете либо лимит, либо плохую строку.

Comment: А зачем вы сначала весь файл засовываете в лист, а потом из листа достаете точки? Читайте построчно, из строки добывайте точку, помещайте ее куда-то там куда вам надо, забывайте строку и читайте следующую.

Comment: оно может то и так, но мы на самом деле не знаем, что там происходит. Может там из за какой то мелкой проблемы все крашится. Но мы пока об этом не знаем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ускорения можно:

- Хранить исходные данные не в текстовом формате, а в бинарном. Операции чтения и записи будут происходить быстрее. И не нужно будет конвертировать строку в числа, где у вас скорее всего происходит ошибка.
- Использоваться класс `QStringView` для операции `split()`, что позволит не совершать лишние копирования строк.